# backup personal facebook post, photo, etc (recall: friendster)

Tags: backup, script, facebook

I need to backup my facebook account. Let me give you my background as it will give you more understanding.

1. I lost my friendster account because the company ceased to operate. It's not about lost password, my negligence, nor hacking related activities.
2. Facebook is under FTC investigation. While i believe facebook will not cease business tomorrow, finding / preparing the tools may take days.

To help answers my questions: here are some hints. They are surely abstract because i don't know what else except prints screens:

1. **Do not advice about manually print screens.**
2. Any API (paid / free) would be good
3. Any robot, trainer, scripts, poweshell, shell, any tools are fine.
4. Any method, anyway, anything, excluding point no 1.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook actually offers a way to do that. No need for external tools. See [Downloading your Info](https://www.facebook.com/help/131112897028467/) on the Facebook help pages:

> You can download your information from your [settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings). To download your
> information:
>
> 1. Click the arrow at the top right of any Facebook page and select Settings
> 2. Click Download a copy of your Facebook data at the bottom of General Account Settings
> 3. Click Start My Archive
>
> Because this download contains your profile information, you should keep it secure and be careful when storing, sending or uploading it to any other services.

Comment: thats cool... i recalled story police chase thief and the thief hides behind the police station. i never check facebook help files, only googling. googling mindset